# Batch delete and batch update

Tags: php, yii

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#delete()-detail

I see in the documentation a batch insert, but no batch delete or batch update. Is there a way to implement a batch update and delete using Yii's db API? What's the best way? I want to avoid using a loop and making several requests. Also, I am using Yii 1.0. I noticed there's no doc for 1.0, will those methods work in 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete or update few rows you should use WHERE. No one make batch delete like this `DELETE ... WHERE id=1; DELETE ... WHERE id=2;` you can do it like this `DELETE ... WHERE id IN(1,2);`

Batch insert for Yii 1 is available only since 1.1.14.

```
$builder=Yii::app()->db->schema->commandBuilder;
$command=$builder->createMultipleInsertCommand('tbl_post', array( array('title' => 'record 1', 'text' => 'text1'), array('title' => 'record 2', 'text' => 'text2'), ));
$command->execute();
```

This is the [doc for 1.0](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.0)